# copy rails table with changed data in migrations

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rails-migrations

I have a table Pizza linked to mystery that currently looks like this

```
|pizza_id|mystery_id|name|description|
|1       |1         |fun |really fun |
|2       |1         |car |it is fast |
|3       |1         |hou |i live!    |
|4       |1         |air |breathy    |
```

and after my migration I would like it to look like this:

```
|pizza_id|mystery_id|name|description|
|1       |1         |fun |really fun |
|2       |1         |car |it is fast |
|3       |1         |hou |i live!    |
|4       |1         |air |breathy    |
|5       |2         |fun |really fun |
|6       |2         |car |it is fast |
|7       |2         |hou |i live!    |
|8       |2         |air |breathy    |
```

Basically i just want to copy the table's data, and paste it back into the same table, but slightly different. To make matters worse, I SUCK at ruby on rails.

I tried, but I just cant figure out the syntax to copy a table, then paste a table back with changed data. To make matters worse my test site is in sqlite, and my production server is in MYSQL. So I cannot just write one or the other it has to use ruby migration syntax.

This [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28089441/how-can-i-move-data-from-one-table-to-another-in-rails-migration) looks helpful, but it is copying into another table, and it uses just ruby not ruby migrations is that legal in a migration? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if data is less then just do this way `Pizza.each{|p| Pizza.create!(:mystry_id => 2, :name => p.name, :description => p.description )}`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used a bit of the stack overflow question I noted, and this is what i came up with. I did end up using migrations though, and it worked fine.

```
def up        
    Foo.find_each do |a|
      a.mystery_id = 1
      a.save!
    end

    Foo.all.each do |a|
      foo = foo.new(
        :name => a.name,
        :name => a.description,
        :mystery_id => 2
      )
      reminderEvent.save!
    end
  end

  def down

    TODO: somehow remove half all with mystery_id = 2
  end
```

Comment: It's important to keep Models out of your migrations.  If the model changes this migration could also fail.  Consider using seeds or a dedicated script.

Comment: but if the model changes the dedicated script will also fail.

is there a way to say 
    foo = foo.new(a.everything_in_a, :mystery_id => 2
          )

Answer (score 4):

Migrations aren't the right thing to use here. Migrations are for adjusting the database structure; they're not for inserting, deleting, or modifying records.

You'll probably want to either use seeds.db (for seeding your database with initial data) OR just perform the operation in rails console or a standalone script.

**For using seeds.db:**

Starting with an empty pizza database and assuming your `Pizza` model contains `belongs_to :mystery`

```
Mystery.create({ /* mystery params */ }) // Create mystery 1
Mystery.create({ /* mystery params */ }) // Create mystery 2

pizza_data = [
  { name: 'fun', description: 'really fun' },
  { name: 'car', description: 'it is fast' },
  { name: 'hou', description: 'i live!' },
  { name: 'air', description: 'breathy' },
]

Mystery.all.each do |mystery|
  pizza_data.each do |pizza_params|
    mystery.pizza.create(pizza_params)
  end
end
```

and then in terminal you want to run `bundle exec rake db:seed`

(see http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/seed_rb.html for more info on seeds.rb)

**For using rails console / script:**

If you want to do it manually using rails console with your pre-existing pizza rows type `rails c` in terminal and enter:

```
Pizza.all.each { |p| Pizza.create(mystery_id: 2, name: p.name, description: p.description) }
```

Comment: the problem with this is that my database is not empty it is quite full. so i cannot use a seed, that is if seeds work like i think they do. i could use a script, but that is kinda a pain.

Comment: That bottom part should be able to do what you were asking without requiring you to have an empty database. You can either paste it into rails console or use it as a script! Hope it helps!